# Node.js application isn't opening up via nginx reverse proxy (Multiple application on different ports)

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

We have multiple node.js applications running on my app servers and we have configured all the application on nginx proxy servers with different port. Now we are trying to add a new application, which works fine in the app server and while trying with proxy it's throwing cannot GET error. Eventhough the upstream are correct which are similar to other application setup.

**app_server_ip:4001** is working and 
**example.com/path/** isn't working

The below configs are App server Nginx configuration.

```
location ~ ^/path/.*$ {
        rewrite ^/path/(.*) /$1 break;
        root /x/y/z/path;
      }

upstream path {
      server 127.0.0.1:4001;
    }
```

The below configs are Nginx Reverse proxy Configuration

```
location ~ ^/path/?(.*)$ {
 rewrite ^/path/(.*) /$1 break;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
 proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
 proxy_pass http://qa_path;
 proxy_set_header IsHttps true;
 proxy_redirect off;
}

upstream qa_path {
      server app_server_ip:4001;
}
```

We need to get the same result what we are getting with app_server_ip:4001

Thanks in advance!